# The global attribute "something" has already been declared

Tags: xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I'm new here. I'm currently working on a Xamarin.Android app, and the last couple of days I've been randomly getting these warnings when working on a layout file. I've searched around for a solution but it I haven't found any yet.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, and the warnings seemingly appear out of nowhere, when there's nothing wrong with the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:weightSum="100">
  <TextView
      android:text="Pos"
      android:textStyle="italic"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:layout_width="35dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/tv_position"
      android:layout_weight="5" />
  <ImageView
      android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/iv_mugshot"
      android:layout_weight="15" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="50">
    <TextView
        android:text="Player"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_player" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Score"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_score" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:layout_width="60dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_weight="30">
    <TextView
        android:text="Playtime"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_playtime" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Difficulty"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv_difficulty" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Over 100 warnings of the same kind, exceeding the limit on number of errors shown. For example:

```
The global attribute 'http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:accessibilityTraversalAfter' has already been declared.
```

The strange thing is, the problem is solved only by quitting Visual Studio and reloading. Then after a while it happens again. The project builds and runs just fine, but Intellisense stops working when that happens (it recognizes wrong code, but the autocomplete list that pops up when writing doesn't show anything.

I installed ReSharper for VS2017 a couple of days ago and thought that might be the reason, so I uninstalled it, but the problem persists. It's really demotivating to have to restart VS multiple times a day because of this. Anyone heard of anything like this before?